# Windows 10 acting erratically

Tags: windows-10, performance

With no warning, my apps and search icons do nothing when I click on either of them.

I can eventually get the folders quick start icon to open that folder, but it takes many seconds to work.

also, with no warning Firefox continually asks if I want it to be the default browser every time I open it.  I click *yes*, and then the grey system window opens where I would otherwise choose default apps.

Firefox is already selected, and I didn't ask that window to open.

Once I'm up and running, the system works as it usually does, but this slow running of programs is new as in 24 hours new.

Ideas, please?

Answer (score 0):

I know this probably sounds obvious but people always overlook the obvious, including myself! Running the System File Checker to check for corrupt files would probably be your best bet and then maybe running the Deployment Image and Servicing Management program if anything corrupt was found and SFC couldn't fix it. To run SFC open an elevated Command Prompt (Admin) and type the following:

```
sfc /scannow
```

For DISM use the same Command Prompt and type:

```
 DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

SysInternals (owned by Microsoft) have some great tools for monitoring whats going on behind the scenes, specifically Process Explorer and Process Monitor. [SysInternals Suite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)